# What are some good data driven astronomy research project ideas for a high schooler?

Tags: research-topic

Does anyone here have sone good astronomy research project ideas for someone with a a background in AI and programming? The projects don't really have to be anything groundbreaking. They could just be confirming something that has already happened or something else that is simple. The only condition is that it should be very data intensive.

Comment: Unfortunately your question is off-topic as we don't discuss specific research projects here. But some ideas could be writing a program that detects bright sources against a dark background (i.e. stars in an image from a telescope), or template fitting for supernova light curve or gravitational wave data.

Answer (score 1):

While I cannot answer your question in substance, I may offer you a glimpse on how you can find a response by yourself. The approach would be to search for 'review' papers discussing your topic of interest.

I thus did a search in *Web of Science* using the query `TOPIC: (astronomy) AND TOPIC: (artificial intelligence) AND DOCUMENT TYPES: (Review)`.

It led me, inter alia, to the paper "[Surveying the reach and maturity of machine learning and artificial intelligence in astronomy](https://doi.org/10.1002/widm.1349)" (2020).

If you access the paper*, you will find some areas of astronomy on p. 10 that are supposedly "emerging" in the sense that the application of AI has only been nascent so far. This might offer a wealth of ideas to you.

Good luck!

---

<sup>* Please do not spend money to buy that paper if you do not have access. There are many cost-free ways to obtain it. For example, just ask a nearby university library, or ask the authors directly to send you a copy.</sup>